# Win32: How to hide 3rd party windows in taskbar by hWnd

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have to hide popup windows in third party library.

I have implemented windows hook stuff with [SetWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990%28VS.85%29.aspx) and know all the newely created hWnd(s). I listen to `HSHELL_WINDOWCREATED` callback and do the following:

```
long style= GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE);
style &= ~(WS_VISIBLE);    // this works - window become invisible 

style |= WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW;   // flags don't work - windows remains in taskbar
style &= ~(WS_EX_APPWINDOW); 

SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE, style);
```

What I do wrong here to hide newely created windows in task bar?

Comment: WS_EX_* need to be get/set with GWL_EXSTYLE - not GWL_STYLE. (WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW has value 0x00000080, which if you use it as a GWL_STYLE instead of an _EXSTYLE, will end up modifying the part of a windows style that's typically not used for app windows, so will seem to be a no-op. The low part of a windows style is typically used for control-specific style bits - eg. for a button, this has the same value as BS_BITMAP.)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Before you use `SetWindowLong`, call `ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_HIDE)`, then call `SetWindowLong`, then call `ShowWindow` again like `ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW)`. So your code will look like this:

```
long style= GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE);
style &= ~(WS_VISIBLE);    // this works - window become invisible 

style |= WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW;   // flags don't work - windows remains in taskbar
style &= ~(WS_EX_APPWINDOW); 

ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_HIDE); // hide the window
SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE, style); // set the style
ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW); // show the window for the new style to come into effect
ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_HIDE); // hide the window so we can't see it
```

Here is a relevant quote from [Microsoft's Website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776822%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> To prevent the window button from being placed on the taskbar, create
>   the unowned window with the WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW extended style. As an
>   alternative, you can create a hidden window and make this hidden
>   window the owner of your visible window.
>
> The Shell will remove a window's button from the taskbar only if the
>   window's style supports visible taskbar buttons. If you want to
>   dynamically change a window's style to one that doesn't support
>   visible taskbar buttons, you must hide the window first (by calling
>   ShowWindow with SW_HIDE), change the window style, and then show the
>   window.

Comment: sorry, it doesn't work for me. Windows that I hide previously successfully  now come visible as well as shown in taskbar.

Comment: @Andrew that's very weird. It might not work, but for curiosity, try `SetWindowLong` after you call `ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);` too. So the code would go `ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_HIDE);
SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE, style);
ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW); SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE, style);`

Comment: @Andrew also what flag are you using as the first parameter to `SetWindowsHookEx`?

Comment: @Andrew and if that modification doesn't work, change the second call to `SetWindowLong` to `ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_HIDE)`

Comment: @Andrew Excellent. Good luck with your project.

Comment: WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW and WS_EX_APPWINDOW flags are exStyles, so, you have to use GWL_EXSTYLE instead of GWL_STYLE.

Comment: What is the point of the last hiding? If the window is invisible, of course it's not in the taskbar. I don't understand why this solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You must use GWL_EXSTYLE to get/set the EX flags, GWL_STYLE will not work for EX flags.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this command in Init function:
ModifyStyleEx(WS_EX_APPWINDOW, WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW);