# Remove Taskbar Icon for a Windows Desktop Monogame Application?

Tags: c#, monogame

Is there a way to remove icon from the taskbar for a monogame windows desktop application?

I tried to re-write the code mentioned in [Win32: How to hide 3rd party windows in taskbar by hWnd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219063/win32-how-to-hide-3rd-party-windows-in-taskbar-by-hwnd) in C#, but it didn't work.

Comment: Why? Taskbar buttons are useful to give the user control over what they're running. How does removing or hiding this button benefit your users?

Comment: It is because I want to call this application from another application and I don't want users to have direct control over it. The control would be from other application.